# Replacing the dialer

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, phone-app

I have recently replaced the stock Samsung system on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with Paranoid Android, but I don't like the dialer.  I have tried a few alternatives and found some I like, but none of them replace the bit that actually makes the calls.

When I use, e.g. Dialer One, I get a great interface that I like, but the moment I press the call or answer button it goes back to the original interface.

Is there any way to completely replace it?

Comment: Well, nope I don't think that you could do that over your end. I would say its over the hands of the developer, or better for you would be getting the source code of the Android downloaded and customise it on your own if you...! Otherwise nope there isn't anyway out !

Comment: In theory you could flash a zip through recovery that has the dialer, the phone itself and all the other necessary elements sure. From my experience though all but one time it was plagued with crashes and errors. It definitely CAN be done but it's very messy. Most Samsung specific features need Touchwiz framework to some degree behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't necessarily want the samsung one, I just don't like the standard android one!  Maybe I should just have a look for a better looking rom...

Comment: Did you set Dialer One as default dialer in its settings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can do this just by installing an app.

I mean, we can't define our new app as default app for making/receiving calls.

So, I think it's in ROM developer's hand. Only they can replace it with custom one, **AFAIK**.

Comment: Not with an apk but you could with a zip in certain cases. You can with a rooted device push it to the `/system` folder also, and replace the existing one, but it rarely works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take the dialer from your old stock ROM, extract from the zip, and install in new ROM. You'll need the app *"/system/app-mover"*, free from playstore, to move stock ROM dialer into the system.  Goto *settings>apps* and disable custom ROM dialer. Your running a custom ROM so this should work, I did this on my HTC.

If this doesn't work out right,  just reverse the steps. No damage to the system.